# How to prove $2\le\frac{g(x)}{g(y)}+\frac{g(y)}{g(x)}$ using AM-GM?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis, convex-analysis, proof-explanation

In this question [Prove that, if $g(x)$ is concave, for $S = {x : g(x) > 0}$, $f(x) = 1/g(x)$ is convex over $S$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532646/prove-that-if-gx-is-concave-for-s-x-gx-0-fx-1-gx-is-c) , in the proof of **Math536**,

> how to prove $2\le\frac{g(x)}{g(y)}+\frac{g(y)}{g(x)}?$

This is the proof of Math536:

### $$\begin{align}
1 &= (a+(1-a))^2 \\
&= a^2 + 2a(1-a) + (1-a)^2 \\
&\le a^2 + a(1-a)\left(\frac{g(x)}{g(y)} + \frac{g(y)}{g(x)}\right) + (1-a)^2 \\
&= (ag(x)+(1-a)g(y)) \left(\frac{a}{g(x)} + \frac{1-a}{g(y)}\right) \\
&\le g(ax+(1-a)y) \left(\frac{a}{g(x)} + \frac{1-a}{g(y)}\right) \\
&= \frac{af(x) + (1-a)f(y)}{f(ax+(1-a)y)}
\end{align}$$

He said we should use the AM-GM inequality which is $\forall a_i\in\mathbb R^+: \frac{a_1+...+a_n}{n}\ge (a_1\dots a_n)^{1/n}.$

I tried to find a similarity with the LHS of the AM-GM inequality:

$$g(x)f(y)+f(x)g(y)\ge\sqrt{g(x)g(y)f(x)f(y)}$$

I honestly don't know how will I get the $2$ in the inequality?

Can someone help me please?

Comment: $$\dfrac{\dfrac{g(x)}{g(y)}+\dfrac{g(y)}{g(x)}}2\ge\sqrt{\dfrac{g(x)}{g(y)}\cdot\dfrac{g(y)}{g(x)}}=2$$

Comment: Don't bother with functions.  For any positive number $x + \frac 1x \ge 2$.  (Pf: if $x > 0$ then $x + \frac 1x \ge 2 \iff x^2 + 1 \ge 2x \iff x^2 -2x +1 = (x-1)^2 \ge 0$.).  So no matter what $x,y$ are $\frac {g(y)}{g(x)} = \frac 1{\frac {g(x)}{g(y)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about *functions*.

For any two $x,y$ then $\frac {g(x)}{g(y)} = k$ will be a positive number, and $\frac {g(y)}{g(x)} = \frac 1k$.

So by AM-GM.  $\frac {k + \frac 1k}2 \ge \sqrt {k*\frac 1k}=1$.

And that's *it*.

....

In fact this basically *is* the proof of the AM-GM.

$(k - 1)^2 \ge 0$ so

$k^2 + 1 \ge 2k$ so

$k + \frac 1k \ge 2$.

Or in general:

$(\sqrt a - \sqrt b)^2 \ge 0$ so

$a + b \ge 2\sqrt{ab}$ so

$\frac {a+b}2 \ge \sqrt{ab}$.

Answer (score 3):

Simply: $$\dfrac{g(x)}{g(y)}+\dfrac{g(y)}{g(x)} = 2+\Bigg(\sqrt{\dfrac{g(x)}{g(y)}} - \sqrt{\dfrac{g(y)}{g(x)}}\Bigg)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for the general AM-GM here. Suppose you have two positive real numbers $a, b > 0$ (justified since $g(x), g(y) > 0$). Then,

$$2 \leq \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a} = \frac{a^2+b^2}{ab} \iff$$
$$2ab \leq a^2+b^2 \iff a^2-2ab+b^2 \geq 0 \iff (a-b)^2 \geq 0$$

with equality iff $a=b$.

Comment: Well, that's basically *is* the proof of the AM-GM theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Put $a_1 = g(x)^2$, $a_2 = g(y)^2$. Then the inequality says

$$\frac{g(x)^2 + g(y)^2}{2} \geq \sqrt{g(x)^2g(y)^2}.$$

Rearrange the inequality, separate the sum and simplify to obtain
$$\frac{g(x)}{g(y)} + \frac{g(y)}{g(x)} \geq 2.$$

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative by [Rearrangement inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality)

assume wlog $g(x)\geq g(y)\implies \frac{1}{g(y)}\geq\frac{1}{g(x)}$

thus

$$\frac{g(x)}{g(y)}+\frac{g(y)}{g(x)}\geq \frac{g(y)}{g(y)}+\frac{g(x)}{g(x)}=2$$